# .Net Maui Blazor App Facebook Login Button and Authentication

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, facebook-login

As we know Facebook Login will no longer support Android embedded browsers (WebViews) for authenticating users. How can we authenticate and login with facebook in dotnet maui blazor app on android and ios? Could you please help me for this issue? Is there any recent example?